# Symfony 5.4 - SerializedName attribute/annotation not working

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 5.4 and can't make SerializedName work at all.
I use the symfony serializer, not JMS.

Wether I use annotations or attribute, when I set a serialized name like this:

```
    #[SerializedName('bar')]
    private $foo;
```

The serialized object still has a `foo` key instead of `bar`.

I also use `nelmio/api-doc-bundle`, and in the example value it generates the `@SerializedName` is used, it says I'll get a `bar` key (but if I use the "try it" button, I get `foo`).

This is for every class in my project, anywhere (on class attributes, getters, inherited attributes…)

If anyone has an idea of what I should check, it would be great. It uses the default symfony serializer and normalizer, nothing custom that would be likely to interfere with the serialization process.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
I don't know why, but the name converter was not passed to the normalizer, I had to manually bind `$nameConverter` to `@serializer.name_converter.metadata_aware`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I juste resolved it:

```
$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
$this->serializer = new Serializer(
    [
        new ArrayDenormalizer(),
        new UidNormalizer(),
        new BackedEnumNormalizer(),
        new DateTimeNormalizer(),
        new ObjectNormalizer(
            classMetadataFactory: new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader())),
            nameConverter: new MetadataAwareNameConverter($classMetadataFactory, new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter()),
            propertyTypeExtractor: new PropertyInfoExtractor([], [new PhpDocExtractor(), new ReflectionExtractor()])
        ),
    ],
    [new JsonEncoder()]
);
```

needed to add `MetadataAwareNameConverter` as name converter and put `CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter` as fallback